# How to get a part of an integer input in Python

Tags: python

Let's say we have for example the input 23, how can we print 2 by itself and 3 by itself.

I was trying to use something like chr() but I failed.

I am getting an input that will be the coordinates of a chess board.
For example if the input is 23, I want to have 2 as the column and 3 as the row.
So I need to split the input so that I can manipulate the code.

Comment: When you say `input`, are you referring to the builtin [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function?

Comment: `list('hello') == ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`. You can also just do `'hello'[0] == 'h'`

Comment: Do you convert it to an integer after you get the input? If so, why? `input(...)` returns a string, and you can index into strings directly to get the first and second character. _Then_ convert those characters to integers.

Comment: If the number is in `x`, `x // 10` will get the tens digit, and `x % 10` will get the units digit.

Comment: @Barmar if you wanna use that approach use divmod, `col, row = divmod(23, 10)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use map() and leverage unpacking

```
coord = "23"
col,row = map(int,coord) # col=2 row=3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input value is a string, you can use string indexing to get each digit,
something like this:

```py
input_value = '23'

column = int(input_value[0])
row = int(input_value[1])

print('column:', column, ' row:', row)
```

Output: `column: 2  row: 3`

If your input value is an integer, you can first turn it into a string using `str()`